# Can't find responsive elements in my markup. I only see them in Firebug

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, firebug

This may be a basic question but I'm new to using Bootstrap, Sass, and to a certain degree CSS3. How is it that certain responsive elements appear but they aren't present in the markup?? Is this JQuery? I want to change the way that my navbar renders when viewed on a mobile phone but I only see the responsive navbar element in my in browser editor. It does not exist in my markup. This leads me to believe that there is a way for elements to be added using SASS, CSS3, or even javascript that I am not yet aware of.

Comment: Any modifications to the `DOM` will be visible in Firebug, but not if you `view-source` of the page.

Comment: Thanks, I get that but I'm not viewing source. I'm "inspecting the element". Problem is, neither the element, nor the class attributed to it, exists in my markup.